# Vagrant Up provisions on one computer but not on another

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to get my Vagrant box setup from my work environment on my home computer but I've been running into issues. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Virtualbox and Vagrant twice now. At work, everything works as expected. At home, nothing. My vagrant file is as follows:

```
Vagrant::configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "saucy64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Allow more memory usage for the VM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  # Fix rights and permissions on shared folder
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/", :mount_options => [ "dmode=777", "fmode=666" ]
  config.vm.synced_folder "./www", "/vagrant/www/", :mount_options => [ "dmode=775", "fmode=644" ], :owner => 'vagrant', :group => 'www-data'

  # Set the timezone to something useful
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"Europe/London\" | sudo tee /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata"
  # Make sure APT is up to date
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"
  # Fix locales
  # config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get -y install language-pack-en"

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = { "fqdn" => "dev.oraculum2.local", "hostname" => "www" }
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "oraculum2.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.options = "--hiera_config /vagrant/hiera.yaml"
  end

end
```

My output looks like this:

```
$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'saucy64'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. This can
mean a number of things.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Of course, I've tried to increase the boot timeout but that had the same effect. I tried to boot in the GUI but it goes to a black screen and never changes.

Using:
Vagrant 1.4.1 and Virtualbox 4.3.6

I'm on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine and that's the same as work as well.

I tried with Vagrant 1.4.3 as well but same result. I'm lost as it worked fine at work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you restore (or re-download) the virtualbox image and boot it normally before trying vagrant?  If booting through the GUI goes to a black screen then it's most likely the vb image or your local vb configuration.  Doesn't look like vagrant...

Comment: I tried to redownload it but still black screen. Tried to reinstall Virtualbox and nothing. I'm so stumped.

Comment: Definitely(ish) not vagrant then.  Have you tried using the virtualbox that's built in to vagrant?  Have a look at [Vagrant's getting started](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html) page, use the precise32 box mentioned there.  And maybe try another VM provider.

Comment: Googling tells me there's problems with guest additions, and with graphics accelerators.  Try a virtualbox with neither of these turned on.

Answer (score 2):

I was initially going to suggest that there are networking issues, but I missed the 'GUI goes to a black screen and never changes' part.

This sounds as if the VirtualBox setup itself seems to have some trouble. I would suggest to try it with a different box as well to determine if it is a problem with the box (maybe a broken download?) or with VirtualBox itself.

Comment: I tried a different box but the same result happened. I'm thinking it's a Virtualbox thing but I tried to redownload it and reconfigure to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

make sure the box user ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys contain the pub key to match your vagrant private key.

I had a very similar problem. vagrant up would abort and virtual box would start just fine.
i would get this:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

i watched open console and see it started up and THEN aborted.
and so i generated debug.

```
VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up >> DEBUG.LOG.0 2>&1 &
```

i walked through that data and saw inside:

```
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO ssh: SSH not up: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHAuthenticationFailed: SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.>
```

i started the virtual box from provider, logged in, checked and vagrant key was corrupt.
replaced it. tested ssh as vagrant without password. shutdown -h now. vagrant up…
SUCCESS!!

the output from vagrant up is misleading. in the debug we can see that it knows where it failed but this is not handled sufficiently to tell the user that the box /may be/ fine, the communication was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command on the terminal

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
```

then check the output on the `IdentityFile` values, e.g.:

```
 IdentityFile /home/{USERNAME}/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

then switch or login to the appropriate SSH user and run `vagrant up`, before login the SSH user, you must "suspend the vagrant box" using `vagrant suspend` command.